# How to create divider in TextView?

Tags: android, xml, textview

[image: a busy cat]

So I want to put divider after Location text that way my text will be more visible and clear. I would like to put Name in Bold too, so if someone can help me with this I would appreciate. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.baseball_activity);
        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        gfR = (GroupedFeed) myIntent.getSerializableExtra(ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE_KEY);


        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String htmlEncodedText = "<HR WIDTH=75 COLOR=#FF0000 SIZE=4>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlEncodedText));
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String NEW_LINE = "\n";
        //String LINE = "<br>";
        for(RssMsg rssMsg : gfR.getFeeds()) {
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append(htmlEncodedText);
            buffer.append(" Name : <HR WIDTH=75 COLOR=#FF0000 SIZE=4>" +rssMsg.getName() + "</HR WIDTH=75 COLOR=#FF0000 SIZE=4>");
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append("   Date : " +rssMsg.getDate());
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append("   Time : " +rssMsg.getTime());
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            if(rssMsg.getEventResult() == null){
                buffer.append("   Event Result : Unavailable");
            }else{
            buffer.append("   Event Result : " +rssMsg.getEventResult());
            }
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append("   Date Revised : " +rssMsg.getDateRevised());
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append("   Event Type : " +rssMsg.getEventType());
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append("   Location : " +rssMsg.getLocation());
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
            buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        }
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDD00"));
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#003767"));
        textView.setText(buffer.toString());
    }
```

and XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@string/title_activity_baseball" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context="com.example.athletic_project.java.Baseball">


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxLines="80" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    android:text="@string/title_activity_baseball" 
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The image is not accessible via given URI, please re-upload it.

Comment: plz upload the image that you wanna provide

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to format your text with HTML and then pass it to the TextView this way:

```
TextView t = ...
String myHtmlText = ...

t.setText( Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText) );
```

From experience, I find html encoding the best approach when it comes to more complex text formatting.

First, in your Activity's `onCreate` method you will want to assign your XML-defined TextView to a Java object. It is done like this:

```
public void onCreate(){

    setContentView(R.layout.[name of the XML you pasted above]);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String htmlEncodedText = ... //Define the text here, with a method, resources call or whatever you like

    t.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlEncodedText));

}
```

Or, basing on the code you provided:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    String NEW_LINE = "<br>";
    for(RssMsg rssMsg : gfR.getFeeds()) {
        buffer.append("Name : <b>" +rssMsg.getName() + "</b>");
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        buffer.append("   Date : " +rssMsg.getDate());
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        buffer.append("   Time : " +rssMsg.getTime());
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        if(rssMsg.getEventResult() == null){
            buffer.append("   EventResult : Unavailable");
        }else{
        buffer.append("   EventResult : " +rssMsg.getEventResult());
        }
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        buffer.append("   DateRevised : " +rssMsg.getDateRevised());
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        buffer.append("   EventType : " +rssMsg.getEventType());
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        buffer.append("   Location : " +rssMsg.getLocation());
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
        buffer.append(NEW_LINE);
    }
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDD00"));
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#003767"));
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(buffer.toString()));
}
```

Comment: so where I have to input this code and how that suppose to look?

Comment: so how I would set up divider?

Comment: What do you mean by a divider? Between what?

Comment: I tried to test but did not work, check my code I did update.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of Divider]

**Solution:**

1. We apply ***append()***, ***"\n"*** and ***SpannableString***.
2. Text written as **"________________________________"** using underlined SpannableString.

   This allows **Color** and **Transparency** to be customizable.

   Read more at: [Hexadecimal color code for transparency](https://bl.ocks.org/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4)

   E.G. To adjust transparency to 49%, we simply use **#7D** as shown below:

> appendUnderlinedText(textmessage, "________________________________" +
> "\n", Color.parseColor("#7D808080"));

**Sample code:**

```
...

TextView textmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmessage);
appendUnderlinedText(textmessage, "________________________________" + "\n", Color.parseColor("#DB808080"));     
…                               
}

public static void appendUnderlinedText(TextView tv, String text, int color) {

int start = tv.getText().length();

tv.append(text);

int end = tv.getText().length();

SpannableString spannableText = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
spannableText.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

}
```

For further clarifications, I made a video on it at [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/SnqQLPnGuQw)